# Is a universally closed monomorphism a closed immersion?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, nonnoetherian

The question is essentially in the title: $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ is a monomorphism of schemes that is universally closed; does this imply that $f$ is a closed immersion? Any such $f$ is quasi-compact by https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04XU, so one may add this assumption if one wants.

In particular, is every integral monomorphism a closed immersion? (This would improve https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03BB)

If $Y$ is locally Noetherian, then the answer is positive and is Proposition 3.8 (i) in Ferrand's "Monomorphismes de schemas noetheriens". But is this perhaps true for any $Y$? Or are there known counterexamples? Of course, I do not want to assume that $f$ is of finite type ;)

Comment: see https://mathoverflow.net/a/152531/143116

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a non-surjective epimorphism $B\to C$ where $B$ and $C$ are zero-dimensional local rings (D. Lazard, see http://www.numdam.org/item/SAC_1967-1968__2__A8_0/). Then $\mathrm{Spec}\,(C)\to \mathrm{Spec}\,(B)$ is a monomorphism but not a closed immersion, and it is universally closed because $B_\mathrm{red}{\simeq}C_\mathrm{red}$.

Comment: I understand that an epimorphism of rings defines a monomorphism in the category of *affine* schemes. Does it necessarily define a monomorphism in the category of all schemes? Is every monomorphism in the category of affine schemes also a monomorphism in the category of all schemes?

Comment: @Ioki: Yes, indeed.

Comment: Could you then kindly include a reference or an argument for that, for people who do not know it?

Comment: If two morphisms from a scheme agree on every affine open, they are equal.

Comment: What happens if we assume that the schemes in question are reduced? Are universally closed monomorphisms of reduced schemes always closed immersions?